# How to develop google actions locally?

Tags: actions-on-google

My question might sound basic or lame to you but I really have zero experience with this. I am so new to Google Actions and I don't have that much idea with Javascript. My question is how do I develop a Google Action without using the online editor google provided? Can you please narrate it to me step by step? I tried enrolling myself in codelab exercises that I hope might help me but in the codelab exercise, there was already a bunch of codes I cloned from github and that was what I used to make it all work. But now that I want to code for our real project, I don't know how to start from scratch. I know how to create an agent and stuff.. but I don't know how to develop locally. PLEASE HELP ME. THIS IS FOR OUR THESIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have followed the [Build Actions for the Google Assistant (Level 2)](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/index.html) codelab, you'll see that it talks about [setting up for local development in step 3](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/index.html#2) using Firebase Cloud Functions. If you scroll down to part 4 on that page, what follows replaces some things in part 4.

Instead of typing `firebase deploy` as it suggests, *instead* type

```
firebase serve --only functions
```

What this does is, instead of sending the code to the server, you run the code locally in an environment that emulates the Firebase Cloud Function configuration. It will show the full path that is available on localhost. If your function is named something like "webhook", it will show something like:

> functions: webhook: http://localhost:5000/your-project/us-central1/webhook

This now lets you use the ngrok command in another window with something like

```
ngrok http 5000
```

and that window will show the URL and hostname that are the external point. So it might be something like:

> forwarding                    https://8ba32042.ngrok.io -> localhost:5000

You would combine these two to make the URL that you should use as the fulfillment webhook URL. Using our example, it would be something like

> https://8ba32042.ngrok.io/your-project/us-central1/webhook

that you would put into the Dialogflow fulfillment URL setting.

You can then stop and start the local firebase hosting as you change things in your code and examine the request and response using the ngrok console. If you ever stop the ngrok command line, when you start it again you'll get a new hostname, and you'll need to change this in Dialogflow as well.

Comment: Hi! Is it okay if I ask for your email? Because I badly need a guide at this :(

Comment: I already installed ngrok and followed everything you said.. But when I try to change the 'firebase deploy' command with the command you stated, it generates an error. The error is 'SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier......'

Comment: Note: I already run the 'firebase deploy' command even before I asked. PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: I do public consulting free since answers can help others. If you are having a problem and can't find the Syntax Error, starting another StackOverflow question with the code and error in question may be an appropriate route.

Comment: @Prisoner: Can you please provide code and screens step by step. It will help us to under stand

Comment: @RameshS - I'm not sure what more you're looking for. I provided both the commands to use in this case and what should appear on the screens. I can add more, but I'm not sure what isn't clear that screen shots will illustrate. **In addition** Be aware that this is an answer to a 4 year old question about a product that is being shut down within the year (Actions on Google). I'm not sure what you're expecting to help. If you have a specific problem that you're encountering, it may be best to pose a completely new question with as much detail as you can to describe the problem.

Comment: @Prisoner: I have tried based on you answer, actually my project running in local and ngrok connected. But while I access the `ngrok` URL it shows `Not found` message. please check this images https://ibb.co/8zmY0jn, https://ibb.co/dM25JS6, 
https://ibb.co/KwFmPZZ

Comment: @Prisoner: please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73031468/google-actions-builder-webhook-url-not-found

Answer (score 2):

- Download [NGROK](https://ngrok.com/download)
- Download NODEJS
- Develop a local webhook using Express on NodeJS
- Expose this local webhook to the internet using NGROK
- Use the NGROK generated URL as the fulfilment to your Dialogflow agent.
- Integrate Google Assistant with Dialogflow and test it.

Here is a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@silvano.luciani/actions-on-google-client-library-for-node-js-v2-0-0-alpha-c92361167f15) to start with

Comment: I think [this is the link to the tutorial](https://medium.com/@silvano.luciani/deploy-your-assistant-app-fulfillment-webhook-using-cloud-functions-for-firebase-da83275ee715).

Comment: The link in my answer has code snippets to start local development