# How to develop google actions from scratch and locally?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm struggling with developing google actions from scratch because in https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/index.html#2 we are given base files.. Now I'm figuring out how to develop google actions locally without base files. Can anyone please teach me step by step? I really have no background in google actions and even in javascript. I'm very new to this and I need to know how to figure this out because this is our thesis. PLEASE DO HELP ME

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to develop google actions locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51816304/how-to-develop-google-actions-locally)

Answer (score 1):

The base files are mostly boilerplate to give you an idea of what you need to add. You certainly don't need to use any of them, but you can use them as a model for what you'll need to do.

Since you're not familiar with Javascript or developing Cloud Functions for Firebase - they are particularly good models to work from. I'm not sure why you want to start from scratch.

Similarly, you don't need to start with the Dialogflow configurations they provide - as long as you have mapped out a design, you can build them yourself from scratch.